# Convert String array to Map using stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have String array and I would like to get Map where Integer - is an index of element of the String array. How I can avoid `no instance(s) of type variable(s) T` for the key of the map in that case?

```
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
String[] a = {"\"a\"", "\"b\"", "\"c\""};
Map<Integer, Integer> map = Arrays.stream(a)
            .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\"", "")) // I need to remove '"' from the string
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o, atomicInteger.getAndIncrement()));
```

Solution which works:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = IntStream.range(0, a.length) .boxed() .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> a[i].replaceAll("\"", ""), i -> i));
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's the expected result for this example?

Comment: What should be the key of the map and value of the map?

Comment: The second argument to `toMap` has to be a lambda expression, e.g. `o -> atomicInteger.getAndIncrement()`. But using an `AtomicInteger` this way is strongly discouraged anyway. Just use `IntStream.range(0, a.length) .boxed() .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> a[i].replaceAll("\"", ""), i -> i));`

Comment: @ernest_k
not an exception, error in IDE: `no instance(s) of type variable(s) T, U exist so that Integer conforms to Function<? extends T, ? extends U>`

Comment: Change `Map<Integer, Integer>` to `Map<String, Integer>` and `atomicInteger.getAndIncrement()` to `o -> atomicInteger.getAndIncrement()`

Comment: some clarification: I except to get Map as
`a > 0, b > 1, c > 2`

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp oops, but this do not help. Oroginally it was `Map<String, Integer>`

Comment: Then follow the @Holger approach in the above comment.

Comment: why do you need `AtomicInteger` to begin with? `IntStream.range(0, a.lenght).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> a[x], x -> x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code:

1. You are using `Map<Integer, Integer>` instead of `Map<String, Integer>`.
2. `toMap()` requires two Functions as parameter, but you are passing a value (`atomicInteger.getAndIncrement()`) instead of a Function (`o -> atomicInteger.getAndIncrement()`).

So the complete example would look like this:

```
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
String[] a = {"\"a\"", "\"b\"", "\"c\""};
Map<String, Integer> map = Arrays.stream(a)
        .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\"", "")) // I need to remove '"' from the string
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), o -> atomicInteger.getAndIncrement()));
```

The result is:

```
{a=0, b=1, c=2}
```

Beside that it would be much better to use an `IntStream` instead of using an `AtomicInteger`:

```
String[] a = {"\"a\"", "\"b\"", "\"c\""};
Map<String, Integer> map = IntStream.range(0, a.length).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> a[i].replaceAll("\"", ""), Function.identity()));
```

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, a.length) .boxed() .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> a[i].replaceAll("\"", ""), i -> i));` also works

Comment: @CyrilDragomyr Yes I added an example to my post.